# MS Access to Execute Proc in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a Proc for creating and updating a table in SQL Sever. The result table is linked to the MS ACCESS FE. It was before created by Macro involving queries in MS Access. How could I call or execute the Proc from MS Access FE.

I tried this code but it doesn't result in anything.

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Server=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE_DATA"
cmd.Execute
```

I'm new to VBA Coding. Any help or leads will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you haven't opened a connection to the database. Open a connection first like in the below code:

```
Private Const gcConn As String = "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Server=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Sub UpdateProc()

Dim oDB As ADODB.Connection
Dim oCM As ADODB.Command

Set oDB = New ADODB.Connection
oDB.Open gcConn
Set oCM = New ADODB.Command

With oCM
    .ActiveConnection = oDB
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "UPDATE_DATA"
    .Execute
End With

oDB.Close
Set oDB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error "Invalid attribute in sub or function" , But you have declared it outside the sub, I have no idea why it is throwing this error.

Comment: Have you put the code inside another procedure or in a blank module?

Comment: Yes within another module which is got several VBA tasks being done.

Comment: The first line needs to be before the first procedure alternatively declare it in the procedure as per update on the answer.

Comment: I included it in a different form in a test MS Access DB. But I don't see the proc to be run, No change on the destination table.

Answer (score 0):

Simply save your command as a pass-though query. Thus your query is:

```
UPDATE_DATA
```

Then this one line of code will run that query

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass").Execute
```

Comment: I get an ODBC Call failed "SQL Server Client 11.0. Also incorrect syntax at "Mypass" #102

CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyProc").Execute

Comment: Since the tables reside on the SQL Server , I had the impression building a proc was a better solution and then execute it from Access. I did some rework and I believe the pass through queries are doing the job for me. Since the the end table results are few thousands n not millions. So the link tables does the job.